# why does the "checkout" button run away from bottom to top left in ie7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

why does the "checkout" button run away from bottom to top left in ie7?
it is view placed in ie6 and firefox.
what happened? how to fix?
demo url: http://linjuming.pydra.org/leb/ie7_checkout_cw/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE7 does not support `:after` css selector. You can modify your `.clearfix` class (which is currently empty) like this:

```
.clearfix {
   clear: both;
}
```

As far as I can see, it works fine that way.

Comment: very good answer ,thank you. and why no body answer my other questions ?

Comment: @linjuming possibly because of their specific. IE6 is rare browser at this moment. Many people forgot it like a bad dream already. And compass sass may be not so widely spread thing. Or possibly something in your questions itself. You may try to use bounties to get more attention to your questions.